# Override IP in HTTP Request

Tags: c#, c++, wininet

Looking for a way to issue an HTTPwebrequest, or use the browser control, or winhttp to make a request to a URL, but override the IP address it connects to from the DNS lookup to a specific one.

Trying to do something similar to the HOSTS file, but programatically without having to modify this file. It can be C# or C+

Why I need it, the host i am sending the request has multiple IPs, and their Domain servers are doing load balancing accross the different IPs. Trying to force the request to a particular IP, but I need the host in the http request to be still the original host. I need this programatically because changing the host file every time i need to run this test is too time consuming.

Answer (score 14):

All you had to do was this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1");
request.Host = "news.bbc.co.uk";
```

Comment: +1 It seems the Host property was apparently added in .NET 4.

Comment: If you do it with reflection in pre 4.0, it won't work, because it will re-overwrite the host header when it sends the request.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you have to make an http request to a web server using virtualhosts but the DNS isn't setup yet so you have to specify the ip address in the url but send something else in the *Host:* header.

If that's the case you may be able to do so..

**In C# using WebProxy:**

**See [Kayode Leonard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8454151) for .NET 4 and up.**

Here's the code I would use if I have my server running on `67.223.227.171:8888` but I need to have `www.example.com` in the `Host:` header.

```
System.Net.WebRequest r = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
r.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://67.223.227.171:8888");
```

See [this link](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/dotnetframework/t14181-httpwebrequest-host-header.aspx)

**In C++ using WinHttp:**

Using WinHttp you can simply set the `Host:` header with WinHttpAddRequestHeaders.

So once again if I have my server running on `67.223.227.171:8888` but I need to have `www.example.com` in the `Host:` header:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
  HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0", 
                                    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                                    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
                                    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

  assert(hSession != NULL);


  // Use WinHttpConnect to specify an HTTP server.
  HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession,
                             L"67.223.227.171",
                             8888,
                             0 );

  assert(hConnect != NULL);

  // Open and Send a Request Header.
  HINTERNET  hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect,
                                 L"GET", 
                                 L"/downloads/samples/internet/winhttp/retoptions/redirect.asp", 
                                 NULL,
                                 WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                                 WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                                 0 );

    assert(hRequest != NULL);

   BOOL httpResult = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(
                                  hRequest,
                                  L"Host: www.example.com",
                                  -1L,
                                  0);

   assert(httpResult);

  httpResult = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 
                                   0,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   0 );

  assert(httpResult);

  httpResult = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

  assert(httpResult);
}
```

**Edited:** The class name is `WebProxy`. Added C# sample code. Added C++ sample code.

Comment: @Alexandre - just tried this - it looked like a pretty novel approach (note in the article he corrects his use of "CustomWebProxy" and says it should just be "WebProxy"). However, it doesn't seem to work - the request still seems to have the original host header. I may be wrong - you can't easily use Fiddler to debug this as Fiddler works by setting a proxy (which this solution specifically overrides). However, having used a tcp packet sniffer it doesn't look like it works. Shame really.

Comment: I've edited my post. Is that of any help? I seem to get the correct header here.

Comment: +1 - I've had a second go - and I think you're right - this does seem to work. Also - good spot on making it "Fiddler debuggable" by setting the proxy to be the Fiddler proxy. Obvious but I just missed it :)   Very neat trick this.

Comment: is there something similar for WINHTTP?

Comment: @httpresearcher looks like it. I've added another sample.

Answer (score 2):

[**Note, further to Kayode Leonard's answer**: A Host property was added to the request in .Net 4.0, making this answer obsolete]

I *think* you are saying that you want to be able to override the ip address for a given host, without changing the host header.

For example, news.bbc.co.uk maps to IP address 212.58.226.139, but you want to be able to map this to another ip address, while *still* presenting the same news.bbc.co.uk "Host" http header to the overriden address. This is what you'd acheive by overriding the HOSTS file as you say, which is slightly different to Jason's answer as his won't present the original "Host" http header.

I don't believe you can do this easily (although I'm about to experiment to find out!). Certainly you can't do the following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1");
request.Headers["Host"] = "news.bbc.co.uk";
```

as this will fail with an error saying you can't modify the "Host" header.

You probably can do it if your are willing to go down a level below the HttpWebRequest and deal at a more TCP level, but I'm not sure how you'd approach it without going down to that level.

[**Edit**]: Having played around with various approaches of overriding HttpWebRequest and WebHeaderCollection, I'm pretty sure it can't be done this way. However, Alexandre Jasmin's answer seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer that relies on `curl` and the `--resolve` command line option.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve

From higher level languages, it's usually possible to invoke `curl`.